# Concatenating two strings with strncat

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

I would like to concatenate two strings, adding a new random character, using **strncat()** so basically I'm doing this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHARACTER_RANGE 25
#define INITIAL_CHARACTER 65

int main(){
    char male[32] = "A", female[32] = "B", new_letter[1], new_name[32];
    srand(time(NULL));

    strcpy(new_name, male);
    strncat(new_name, female, sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1);

    new_letter[0]= (rand() % CHARACTER_RANGE) + INITIAL_CHARACTER;

    strncat(new_name, new_letter, sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1);

    printf("New string is %s!\n", new_name);

    return 0;
}
```

In case of new letter is *F* expected result should be:

```
New string is ABF!
```

Instead, the result is:

```
New string is ABFAB!
```

I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: It seems like a typo, please use one consistent macro name `CHARACTER_RANGE` or `CHARACTERS_RANGE`.

Comment: @hiimdaosui: most probably a typo unrelated to the actual issue, I took the liberty to fix it.

Comment: @chqrlie I tried as well. Got prevented by the 6 chars limit.

Comment: Should the desired string not fit in `new_name[32]`, how do you want this reported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second call to `strncat` is incorrect:

```
strncat(new_name, new_letter, sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1);
```

`new_letter` is not a proper C string, as it does not have a null terminator, nor is there any space to store it after the letter. If `sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1` is greater than `1`, the behavior is undefined.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CHARACTER_RANGE 25
#define INITIAL_CHARACTER 65

int main() {
    char male[32] = "A", female[32] = "B", new_letter[2], new_name[32];

    srand(time(NULL));

    strcpy(new_name, male);
    strncat(new_name, female, sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1);

    new_letter[0] = (rand() % CHARACTER_RANGE) + INITIAL_CHARACTER;
    new_letter[1] = '\0';

    strncat(new_name, new_letter, sizeof(new_name) - strlen(new_name) - 1);

    printf("New string is %s!\n", new_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the call to `strcpy` is performed without a protection. In this particular example, the source string fits into the destination buffer, but for a more generic approach, there is a simpler method to construct strings within fixed array boundaries with `snprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CHARACTER_RANGE   26
#define INITIAL_CHARACTER 'A'

int main() {
    char male[] = "A", female[] = "B", new_name[32];

    srand(time(NULL));

    snprintf(new_name, sizeof new_name, "%s%c",
             rand() % 2 ? female : male, 
             rand() % CHARACTER_RANGE + INITIAL_CHARACTER);

    printf("New string is %s!\n", new_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux: you are absolutely correct, from `A` to `Z`.